# Node.js JavaScript Datatype

Tags: javascript, node.js

Am learning Node.js.
Could anyone explain what does this mean?
What data type is this one and how is it useful?

```
var x = { a = { n: 0 } };
```

Comment: It creates an object with an A property that contains an object with an N property. After you fix your syntax error that is.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/met_assert_deepequal.asp

Comment: It's not the first time and probably won't be the last that W3Schools hosts incorrect material.

Comment: The syntax error is `a =` that should read `a: `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're trying to learn is how an object works.

The question you asked actually has some bad syntax and should be re-written like this.

```
let x = {
  a: {
    n: 0
  }
}
```

enter image description here

What you're looking at is a nested javascript object and how it's used. The image attached is in Chrome's console and accessing each key of the object. So initially the object is assigned to x. Inside of x there's a key of a. x.a is also an object with a key of n which has the value of 0 assigned to it. So x.a.n === 0. Objects can have multiple data types and are used very often in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to learn is how an object works.

The question you asked actually has some bad syntax and should be re-written like this.

```
let x = {
  a: {
    n: 0
  }
}
```

[image]

What you're looking at is a nested javascript object and how it's used. The image attached is in Chrome's console and accessing each `key` of the object. So initially the object is assigned to `x`. Inside of `x` there's a key of `a`. `x.a` is also an object with a key of `n` which has the value of `0` assigned to it. So `x.a.n === 0`. Objects can have multiple data types and are used very often in javascript.